# bottom-up minimal-change algorithm issue

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, repeat

Im trying to get all the permutations of the number 4 so like 1,12,21,123,132,...1234,1243,1423,4123,...ect (there are 24) and we have to use the  bottom-up minimal-change algrothem but in my code when it should be moving on it gets stuck at 1,2 and 2,1 sooo i was wondering if anyone could help. My code is a method that you call and give a number then it should give you back a list of all the permutations. All the print statments where for debugging so in the end they wont be there. Any help would be amazing! Thanks

```py
def min_change(num):
    end=[]
    A=[]
    for i in range(1,num):
        A.append(i)
        print("appened i",A)
        end.append(A)

        for j in end:
            print("entered j",j)
            if len(j)==i:
                print("made past if")
                if len(j)!=1:             
                    x=len(j)-1
                    while x>0:
                        print("this is x ",x)
                        B=A
                        end.append(B)
                        temp=B[x-1]
                        B[x-1]=B[x]
                        B[x]=temp
                        print(B)
                        x=x-1

    return end
```

Comment: Have you tried doing the permutations of 2, then 3...?

Comment: why should `len(j)==i`? Is `j` a list?

Comment: So the code is doing every permutation up to the number entered and the reason why I have len(j)==i is so it doesnt touch say the perms of 3 when on 4

Comment: Try printing `len(j)` and convince me `j` is a list then tell me what the comparison `len(j)==i` is doing.

Comment: The thing about debugging is making sure your assumptions don’t blind you to what’s actually happening - just printing things out will help dispel some illusions.

Answer (score -2):

You can use [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) for that task:

```
# Option 1.
list(it.chain(*(it.permutations(range(1, i+1)) for i in range(1, 5))))

# Option 2.
list(j for i in range(1, 5) for j in it.permutations(range(1, i+1)))
```

The output are the 33 different possible permutations:

```
[(1,),
 (1, 2),
 (2, 1),
 (1, 2, 3),
 (1, 3, 2),
 (2, 1, 3),
 (2, 3, 1),
 (3, 1, 2),
 (3, 2, 1),
 (1, 2, 3, 4),
 (1, 2, 4, 3),
 (1, 3, 2, 4),
 (1, 3, 4, 2),
 (1, 4, 2, 3),
 (1, 4, 3, 2),
 (2, 1, 3, 4),
 (2, 1, 4, 3),
 (2, 3, 1, 4),
 (2, 3, 4, 1),
 (2, 4, 1, 3),
 (2, 4, 3, 1),
 (3, 1, 2, 4),
 (3, 1, 4, 2),
 (3, 2, 1, 4),
 (3, 2, 4, 1),
 (3, 4, 1, 2),
 (3, 4, 2, 1),
 (4, 1, 2, 3),
 (4, 1, 3, 2),
 (4, 2, 1, 3),
 (4, 2, 3, 1),
 (4, 3, 1, 2),
 (4, 3, 2, 1)]
```

Comment: But this is not using bottom-up minimal change algorithm

Comment: I think you missed the point of the OP’s question: he is trying to write code to solve this problem himself, and is asking for help with that code.

Comment: This does get me what I want but I have to use the bottom up way to do so I cant use any tools but thanks for trying